# Java BigInteger to represent unsigned long

Tags: java, long-integer, biginteger, unsigned

I'm trying to use `BigInteger` for representing an unsigned 64 bit (`long`) coming from C in java and my approach is exactly same as mentioned in the following post.

http://technologicaloddity.com/2010/09/22/biginteger-as-unsigned-long-in-java/

Can one of you please validate that this approach is correct?

Any help in this regard appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certainly, but do you really need it? There's a major performance cost. The only time you need it unsigned is when comparing, which you can fix with a small unsigned-compare method. The rest of the time you can just use a long.

Comment: +1, and you don't need to write your own method.  I'm sure many libraries for doing unsigned operations exist; Guava is one: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html

Comment: Thank you for confirming. The usecase is not very performance sensitive, so I'm not much concerned on that point.Still for a better understanding, how the case unsigned c Long.MAX will be mapped to java long if I use long as you mentioned.or may be I missed some point.  @Mark,  I came across the guava library, but in my case I have only one scenario where I need this operation, so didnt bring a new library.

Comment: If performance isn't an issue then I would personally use the Guava `UnsignedLong` wrapper as it removes any ambiguity as to the number is representing.

Comment: @Aham A long has 64 bits, whether signed or unsigned. The only difference is whether it compares < 0 or not. -Long.MAX_VALUE *is,* not just 'maps to' 0x8000000000000001, unless I have fouled up my twos-complement again.

Comment: You can compare two unsigned longs with `a + Long.MIN_VALUE <=> b + Long.MIN_VALUE` where `<=>` is your choice of comparison. for `==` and `!=` you can just compare `a` and `b`. Operations `+`, `-`, `<<`, `>>>` and `*` work the same way. `/` and '%' are different if the top bit is set.

Comment: @Aham: Guava is one of those libraries that I guarantee you will use for other things if you bring it in now.  It rolls up hundreds of best practices into library code, adds functional-like extensions to the collections framework, and turns many verbose operations into one liners (e.g. `CharStreams.toString(Reader)`).  Just pull it in at the first chance you get, and you will wonder how you lived without it.

Comment: You also need unsigned for encryption because of bit rotations.